# Checked do radio button com listagem da consulta sql

Tags: php, html, sql, radiobutton

Boa tarde, tenho uma consulta que me retorna `radio buttons` com alguns resultados do BD para posterior manuseio, no entanto quando coloco o `checked` ele fica marcado no ultimo resultado da tabela, como posso fazer para que ele fique marcado no primeiro resultado??
segue codigo

```
<?php
    $list_platform_don = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM type_donations WHERE platform_id ='.$_SESSION['platform']);
    $list_platform_don->execute();
    foreach($list_platform_don as $donate):
        echo '<input type="radio" name="donate_opt" class="donate_opt" value="'.$donate['coupons'].'" checked><p>'.$donate['name'].' </p><img src="imagens/'.$donate['img'].'">';
    endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se "lista_platform_don" é um array, uma forma de marcar o primeiro elemento seria assim:

```
foreach($list_platform_don as $index => $donate):
if ($index == 0) {
echo '<input type="radio" name="donate_opt" class="donate_opt" value="'.$donate['coupons'].'" checked><p>'.$donate['name'].' </p><img src="imagens/'.$donate['img'].'">';
} else {
echo '<input type="radio" name="donate_opt" class="donate_opt" value="'.$donate['coupons'].'" ><p>'.$donate['name'].' </p><img src="imagens/'.$donate['img'].'">';
}
endforeach;
```

Comment: entendi, no caso o index é usado para gerenciar os arrays separadamente, nao sabia muito bem como funciona essa questao de array, vou testar aqui

Comment: funcionou muito bem, vlw